# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\copia-prueba\vistas\menu.php on line 117

Tags: php

buenas tardes, alguien podría ayudarme a entender, el ¿por qué me sale ese error? De ante mano muchas gracias, les dejo las líneas de código.

```
            <?php $uri = end( explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <?php if($uri == 'home.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="home.php"><strong>Inicio</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'info.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="info.php"><strong>Info</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'usuarios.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="usuarios.php"><strong>Altas</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'archivos.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="archivos.php"><strong>Archivos</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Cual es la linea 17?

Comment: Un `Notice` no es un error. Dicho esto, en el bloque de código no se ve algo que haga referencia al mensaje que indicas. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento del sitio y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Answer (score 2):

Mi respuesta está orientada a ayudar en entender lo que pasaba en tu código, el por qué de la Noticia:

```
Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in ...
```

Si lees la [documentación de `end` en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.end.php), verás que esta función recibe como parámetro un array (el que se obtiene con `explode` en tu caso). Y dice lo siguiente de ese parámetro (las negritas son mías):

> ### Parámetros
>
> #### `array`
>
> El array. Este array es pasado por referencia porque es modificado por la función. Esto significa que **se debe pasar una
>   variable real y no una función que devuelve un array porque solamente
>   variables puede ser pasadas por referencia**.

En palabras llanas, `end` modifica el array que recibe como parámetro poniendo el puntero al final del mismo y por tanto tiene que ser pasado por referencia. El lenguaje PHP tiene una restricción que dice que solamente las variables pueden ser pasadas por referencia, las funciones que devuelven cualquier valor u objeto no pueden ser pasadas por referencia, como es el caso de `explode`.

Otra cosa, aunque una *Notice* no es un error grave, no conviene ignorarlas. Es bueno tener un código lo mejor optimizado posible y muchas veces con las evoluciones del lenguaje una *Notice*  puede llegar a ser un error grave que interrumpla el funcionamiento normal del código.

#### Solución

Ya ha sido explicada en otra respuesta. Es tan simple como asignar el resultado de `explode` a una variable y pasarla como parámetro de `end`:

```
$mParts = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$uri = end($mParts);
```

---

Para más detalles puedes consultar [*Pasar por referencia*, en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas asignar el resultado de `explode()` a una variable asi:

```
<?php $temp = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
      $uri = end($temp); ?>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li <?php if($uri == 'home.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="home.php"><strong>Inicio</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'info.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="info.php"><strong>Info</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'usuarios.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="usuarios.php"><strong>Altas</strong></a></li>
                <li <?php if($uri == 'archivos.php') echo "class='active'"; ?>><a href="archivos.php"><strong>Archivos</strong></a></li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias :)

Comment: Me ayudó mucho tu comentario, que tengas excelente día :D

Comment: De nada y bienvenida.